# Linq Join Null Reference

Tags: c#, linq, join

My query is as follows:

```
(from c in countries
 join r in Db.PaymentRates_VisaImmigrationPermit on c.CountryId equals r.HomeCountryId into countryRates
 from legalRate in countryRates.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join hostC in Db.Countries on legalRate.HostCountryId equals hostC.Id
 select new [...]
```

I get a null reference exception on this line:

```
join hostC in Db.Countries on legalRate.HostCountryId equals hostC.Id
```

... Which is obviously caused by this line:

```
from legalRate in countryRates.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

How can I do the join only if the `legalRate` isn't null; so as to get the data I want without incurring a null reference exception?

Similar question: [Error in LINQ Left JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106537/error-in-linq-left-join)

Comment: Try adding where legalRate.HostCountryId != null to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value of your `legalRate` using the `DefaultIfEmpty` constructor:

```
 from legalRate in 
     countryRates.DefaultIfEmpty(new CountryRate { HostCountryId = int.MaxValue })
```